# Time taken for Bitmap to Allocation

Tags: android, bitmap, renderscript

I've been experimenting with Renderscript for a little while now. I've written small test kernels to do histogram, filtering, etc on images from local storage to verify their functionality. If I get the trace for this sequence of operations - at 8MP image size - by far the most time is taken by the `Allocation.createFromBitmap` call. I see something like 22 ms for this call as against ~1ms for my kernel to run.

As a result, the gain offered by RS is more or less completely wiped out by this overhead. Is this unavoidable or am I missing something basic?

Thanks,

Akshay

Comment: 1ms seems fast for an 8mp kernel.   If you add a finish right after the kernel call and before your timing code, does the timing change?

Comment: Oh wow. That changed everything. Now my total time has gone up by a second or so. In traceview, RenderScript.finish is taking up 1292ms though the timing for my kernels as such hasn't changed.

So if I were to write a bunch of sequential operations, Gray Scale -> Threshold -> Gaussian Downsample then between these kernels, do I have to explicitly call finish in between? And then does it make sense to write two unrelated operations in sequence so that asynch behaviour doesn't matter?

Comment: No need to call finish in between.  But just be aware for timing that even though the call returns doesn't mean its finished.  Things will buffer up until you need the results.  This often makes the copy back seem much slower than it is because its waiting for previous operations to finish so it can return the results.  The RS interface is a pipeline so the operations will always run in the order you issued them even though it returns after queueing the commands.

Comment: Thanks. I have a better idea of this now.

What I can take away though, is that profiling tools like traceview are unreliable in the sense that I cannot reliably conclude on pure RS kernel execution time. At the most I can get an idea of the speed up by looking at total execution time for my whole app.

Are there any profilers available (or in the pipeline) that might be  better suited for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution to this is "USAGE_SHARED".  Which API version are you testing against?

New (API 18+) RS implementation will create allocations with this flag by default.  You should still call copyTo/From but they may (should) turn into NOPs.  The HW drivers are still improving support for this usage flag and will in some cases fall back to an actual copy.  Over time you should see the copy overhead disappear on newer devices.

Comment: I'm using 19 for the most part, 18 when testing with the GS4. So in ideal case, there should be no overhead as the memory is just shared between java and native?

Comment: Yes, It sounds as if the driver on that device is still doing copies behind the scenes.  You can force it to our reference driver with "adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1" and see if the overhead goes away.

Comment: Will try this. But as you said above, perhaps the copy time (for copyTo) is absorbing the wait for kernel completion and that is what I'm seeing here.